# Should a reviewer do research when a question asks "when is feature X coming out?" before VTC?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Currently on Anime and Manga.SE when a question asks *"when is Series X coming out?"* or *"will there be a Season # of X"* i do a quick google search, if i find nothing creditable in the first 10 or so results, i VTC (Vote to Close) as off-topic using the prefab off-topic reason about unannounced future events.

Arqade as a similar off-topic prefab close reason

> Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means.

i came across [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302211/30879) asking about when the rest of the story mode in pokemon duel will be released.

[image: image incase if it's deleted]

now ignoring that it could be closed for the website request since that's off-topic, if i was to go to vote to close this as off-topic because it's a question about unreleased content of a game, should i do some research to see if i can verify that there isn't a official statement indicating an answer to this?

while the subject is the above question i am asking on a more general basis given that with Online Distribution you have DLC, Mobile and Early Access games you're bound to see more *"when will feature X be added/released"* for games that have been released in a certain capacity but add on more content (ie. Pokemon Go - when will gen # pokemon be avalible?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the big reasons we avoid answering stuff like this before games are out is that because before a game is actually released, EVERYTHING CAN CHANGE. Releases can be pushed back, features can be added/removed, stories can change, games can be completely shoved into a deep dark dumpster never to be seen again.

So it's not just about finding an official source (although that's part of it - for things that aren't released, finding something "official" can be incredibly difficult), but it's about knowing that that source's content/explanation/information isn't going to change a million times before launch. We have enough trouble keeping up with stuff that changes after the game releases (I'm looking at you, [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), or any other game that is in a state of "unfinishedness" even though it's technically "released"), this adds a whole other level of uncertainty.

So no, I don't think it's wrong to VTC these things without large piles of research - if we happen to get lucky and there is Word of God out there that people think can be trusted, we can hash that out on an individual basis.

Because putting things on hold is intended to be possibly temporary (that's part of why it was changed from being "closed" to "on hold" - "on hold" sounds more like "oh hey hold up you need to tuck in your shirt and shine your shoes before you run out on stage" and less "here is your home it is a dumpster and it is on fire"), so if there is enough proof and enough people can agree that this thing will not change, they can use their votes as they will. (This is not to say it will be opened or should be opened, it's just a thing that might theoretically be possible in the vastness of time and space).